# Combining multiple dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have 5 dataframe (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`, `df4`, `df5`). All have same columns and column names (NIR database). I would like to frist combine `df1` and `df2` into `df12` and then `df3`, `df4` and `df5` into `df345` and finally combine `df12` and `df345` into `df`. (It has to be this two stages).

```
df12 <- do.call(rbind, list(df1,df2))
df345 <- do.call(rbind, list(df3,df4,df5))
df <- do.call(rbind, list(df12,df345))
newdf <- data.frame(oiltype="olive",nir=df[2:276]);
```

With this I got one of the column names become `nir.nir.V4` while I need it to be `nir.V4`.

I think this is due to the use of list. I would like to know if there's any alternative to combine multiple dataframes without having to face this trouble. Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Please consider showing few lines of example dataset and expected output based on that.

Comment: If there are only 5 dataset, why can't you do `rbind(rbind(df1, df2), rbind(df3, df4, df5))` (it is not clear why this cannot be done in a single step i.e. `do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern=paste0('df', 1:5))))`

Answer (score -1):

I have 5 data.frame df1, df2, df3, df4, df5 having same columns and column names.

```
> df1
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
> df2
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> df3
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
> df4
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
> df5
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
13          4.8           3          1.4         0.1  setosa
14          4.3           3          1.1         0.1  setosa
15          5.8           4          1.2         0.2  setosa
```

For combining df1 and df2

```
> df12 <- rbind(df1,df2)
> df12
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

For combining df3, df4, df5 do the same as above

```
> df345 <- rbind(df3,df4,df5)
> df345
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
```

And at last combining newly formed data frame can be done in similar way

```
> df <- rbind(df12,df345)
> df
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: With examples it is easy to see the effect of combinig data frame using rbind.

Comment: But your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: Can you help me how i can improve my answer

Comment: Thanks Jaap and Deepak. As suggested, I just use rbind straight away without list. Thank you very much.  -f